# How to allow all permissions on all s3 buckets with suffix -dev

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have a lot of buckets that are going to be used by developers. All these buckets have a suffix of "-dev" (E.g. my-bucket-dev, some-other-dev). So I wanted to give all permissions to any bucker having the "-dev" suffix. But it doesn't work.

I have tried the below policy in IAM, but it does not work and I can't figure out why.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*-dev",
                "arn:aws:s3:::*-dev/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It works fine for me. What do you mean by "it does not work". How did you test it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add  "Principal" i guess. Try adding principle

`"Principal": "*",`

Comment: I tried, but "Principal" is not supposed to be used in IAM Policies

Comment: `Principal` is for resource policy

Answer (score 0):

Your policy worked perfectly fine for me.

I tested it via:

```
aws s3 ls s3://myname-dev
```

It gave access to any bucket ending with `-dev`.